# Changing SlideShow Indicator Into Other Shape

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry to change the question midway but there is also something more that I would like to ask.

I'm currently using a default shape of slideshow indicator which is a dot/bullet shaped indicator.

Questions :

- Is there anyway to change it into other shape like rectangular shape ?

Because of time constraint I don't have much time to make a slideshow from scratch so I just grab this code mostly from W3School sites and used it as it is.

Here's a part of the HTML code :

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
        <h1 class="page_title">IR</h1>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/library/results_briefing/"></a>
      <img src="/ir/images/slider_img02.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/investment/event/"></a>
      <img src="/ir/images/slider_img01.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/library/"></a>
      <img src="/ir/images/slider_img03.jpg" alt="IRA" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">IRA</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/business/message/"></a>
        <img src="/ir/images/slider_img04.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/calendar/"></a>
      <img src="/ir/images/slider_img05.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
    </div>
```

Here's the javascript

```
<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    var timer = null;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
clearTimeout(timer);
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
clearTimeout(timer);
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
    }
    </script>
```

And the CSS :

```
* {box-sizing: border-box}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 1000px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-top: -22px;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* Caption text */
.text {
background-color: #424242;
color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.8;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .1}
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .1}
to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
.prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you change a bit in your CSS. Try this code.

```
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
```

This is to remove underline in arrow while hover,

```
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: happy to help! would you mind ticking as right answer? :)

Comment: Ow yeah if I can ask you one more thing, every time I put the cursor at the next button, a underline will show below the button. Is there a way to remove it ??

Comment: I guess you would have to add a bit more css code. I have included in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code

```js
  var slideIndex = 1;
    var timer = null;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
clearTimeout(timer);
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
clearTimeout(timer);
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
    }
```

```css
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-top: -22px;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* Caption text */
.text {
background-color: #424242;
color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.8;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .1}
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .1}
to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
.prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  border-radius:0px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">
        <h1 class="page_title">IR</h1>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/library/results_briefing/"></a>
      <img src="/ir/images/slider_img02.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/investment/event/"></a>
      <img src="/ir/images/slider_img01.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/library/"></a>
      <img src="/ir/images/slider_img03.jpg" alt="IRA" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">IRA</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/business/message/"></a>
        <img src="/ir/images/slider_img04.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <a href="/ir/calendar/"></a>
      <img src="/ir/images/slider_img05.jpg" alt="A" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">A</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
    </div>
```